# UITableView doesn't scroll when number of items is less than scrollable limit

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've a UITableView and I populate data from a service. When the number of rows is higher than what could be displayed on the screen, I'm able to scroll the table. But when it's less (say 1 or 2), I'm unable to scroll (in the sense, the bouce effect doesn't work making the UI appear odd).

I think this should be fixed by some IB checkbox, but not sure how to do it. Anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me was to set `bounces` to `YES` programmatically in `viewDidLoad`.

I also have bounces set to `YES` using the checkbox in IB. It does appear to be taking the IB value because bouncing *will* work after I've pushed another view controller onto the navigation controller stack and then popped it back off. However, bouncing won't work when the table view first appears unless I set `bounces` to `YES` in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the table view and look at the Attributes Inspector. There's a checkbox for Bounce Scroll. (I just tested this in a project that had a 2-line table; disabling it prevented scrolling, enabling it allows the short table to bounce)

I think the programatic equivalent is the [`bounces`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces) property.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this table view as a cell inside another table view?